# IF condition with Postgres; ERROR: syntax error at or near "END" Position: 799

Tags: postgresql, if-statement

I'm trying to write a sql query to pick some columns based on predetermined conditions. I removed the `ELSEIF THEN` following block from the code pasted below for which I get the following error:
`ERROR: syntax error at or near "END"   Position: 799`

Could you please help?

```
Do $$
BEGIN
IF {{f_add_cols_check}} THEN
SELECT colA,colB
   FROM"XXX"  
 
END IF;
END;
$$
```

Comment: Your `select` has no semicolon terminator.

Comment: Additionally, since it is in a plpgsql block your select statement requires an INTO clause, which is missing as is the variables to hold the values selected.